# Why is my useReducer state not updated after refresh API call in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, react-context

I have a `useContext` state that I am using to store user token and I would like to update that state after `axios` interceptor function that calls my `refresh` token endpoint successfully. The state is like this
`state = { in_memory: null}`
I have a reducer function that I use to update it. It works well but doesn't work on an `api` refresh call.
This is the reducer function:

```
 `case actionEnum.SET_IN_MEMORY_VARIABLE:
        return{
            ...state,
            in_memory: action.payload
        }
    `
```

How do I approach this method? Here is the code that I have but it is not updating the reducer state.
I am doing this on a Next.js application. I used same method in a Create React application and it worked. The idea that I would like to do is when the `refresh` endpoint is called, a new `access token` generated, the `state.in_memory` reducer state should be updated to be available across the app.

```
 const refreshToken = async()=>{   

    try {
      const res = await axios.post<axiosGetRefreshTokenAttributes>(`${BASE_URL}/refresh`, {}, {withCredentials: true});

      const accessToken = res?.data?.userToken
        dispatch({type: actionEnum.SET_IN_MEMORY_VARIABLE, payload: accessToken});//This was to update the reducer state with the new access token to be available globally

      return accessToken
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    } 
  }

 return refreshToken
 };
```

This is the `axios` interceptor code:

```
const useAxiosPrivate = () =>{

const refreshToken = RefreshFunction()
const {state, dispatch, setRevalidate, revalidate } = useContext(BookingContext);


useEffect(() =>{
 
    const requestInterceptors = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
        async config =>{
            if(!config.headers['authorization']){
              
                const turf = localStorage.getItem('turf')                    

                if(turf){
                    config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${turf}`
                    config.withCredentials = true
                   
                   
                }
               
                
            }
            return config;
        }, (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
        async (error)=>{
            const prevRequest = error?.config;
            console.log(error.response.status, 'kkk')
            if(error?.response.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent){
                prevRequest.sent = true;
                
                const getTurf = await refreshToken()
                
                 prevRequest.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${getTurf}`;
                
                 
                 return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                
               
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
   
    return()=>{
        axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptors)
        axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept)
    }

  }, [state.in_memory, state.sessionPath])

 return axiosPrivate;   
  };
 export default useAxiosPrivate;
```

An example of an `api` call:

```
 await axiosPrivate.post(`/createcompany`, companyData,  {withCredentials: true, headers: 
  {Authorization: `${state?.in_memory}`}});
```